# How to show the number of record against each user id into my view file: Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, rows

I have fetched the record in my model against each user from database as follows:

```
public function counter_records() {

$table = 'usersearchs';
$this->db->select("domain, time");

$this->db->from($table);
$this->db->where("user_id", $this->session->userdata("user_id"));
$res = $this->db->get();
$num_of_records = $res->num_rows();

return $num_of_records;
}
```

Now I want to show these number of records into a view file for each user account, they have to know how many records they have.

Comment: use group by users, and why r u using where ? if u want all user

Comment: or you want to show all records against user_id to user?

Comment: yes i want to show all the records for a user that is currently logged in with their ID. so why i have fetched them according to the ID.

Comment: than your query is fine, what error you are facing?

Comment: i just need a way to show these records to a profile view. profile_view.php
i have get this model function in my controller as:
            $this->load->model('user_model');
             $data['show_domains'] =  $this->user_model->counter_records();
            $this->load->view('profile_view', $data);

Comment: yes i got the idea, and explained in detail in my answer... well just check the HTML section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this function for display all records against user_id in your **Model**:

```
public function userData()
{
    $results = array();
    $table = 'usersearchs';
    $this->db->select("domain, time");
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->where("user_id",$this->session->userdata("user_id"));
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $num_of_records = $query->num_rows();
    if($num_of_records > 0){
        $results = $query->result_array();
    }   
    return $results;    
}
```

**In Controller:**
call this function in your controller file like.

```
$this->load->model('model_yourmodel');
$data['records'] = $this->model_yourmodel->userData();
```

And pass this data in your view from controller as like:

```
$this->load_view("yourviewpath" , $data);
```

**In HTML View File:**
Use loop for display this data like that:

```
<?
$total_records = count($records);
if($total_records <= 3){
echo (4-$total_records). " records remaining in your account";
}
else{
echo "You have reached the maximum record";
}

if($total_records > 0){  // $records that you have pass from your controller.
   foreach($records as $value){
   ?>
   // Your HTML Code 
   Domain <?=$value['domain']?> - Time <?=$value['time']?> <br/>
   // Your HTML Code
   <?
   }
}
else{
   // your HTML
   echo "No record found";
   // your HTML
}
?>
```

**Result should be like that in HTML:**

```
domain1 - time1 
domain2 - time2 
domain3 - time3 
domain4 - time4 
domain5 - time5
```

Comment: can you please tell me. how i can show the number of rows for each user. i.e that a user has 5 records in database so i t will show 5 with domain and time?. @devpro

Comment: actually there is a limit of 4 records for each user. if someone have 3 records in their account then i have to show 1 is remaining. how i could do this?

Comment: the above code is already working i have show them to their account now the next thing is the records limit. we have to tell them how many remaining records they have from total amount.

Comment: Allright @ShoaibFareed: i have my answer check HTML section top conditions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99137/discussion-between-devpro-and-shoaib-fareed).